# how to fetch value of each fID in this array

Tags: arrays, concrete5

I want to have the fID value from this value to use this further. Could somebody help me out.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [slideshowImgId] => 126
            [bID] => 84
            [fID] => 1
            [url] => 
            [duration] => 0.5
            [fadeDuration] => 0
            [groupSet] => 0
            [position] => 0
            [imgHeight] => 212
            [descriptionLink] => 
            [descriptionHeading] => new1
            [descriptionParagraph] =>                                           new1body
            [transitionNum] => 3
            [transitionSlicing] => vertical
            [transitionDirection] => down
            [transitionFader] => none
            [transitionDelay] => 0.1
            [transitionZmultiplier] => 2
            [iframecontent] =>
        )

```
[1] => Array
    (
        [slideshowImgId] => 127
        [bID] => 84
        [fID] => 4
        [url] => 
        [duration] => 0.5
        [fadeDuration] => 0
        [groupSet] => 0
        [position] => 1
        [imgHeight] => 150
        [descriptionLink] => 
        [descriptionHeading] => new2
        [descriptionParagraph] =>                                               new2
        [transitionNum] => 3
        [transitionSlicing] => vertical
        [transitionDirection] => down
        [transitionFader] => none
        [transitionDelay] => 0.1
        [transitionZmultiplier] => 2
        [iframecontent] =>                                              
    )
```

)

Answer (score 0):

This is a horribly, absurdly, poor question, but I'll give it a shot:

```
foreach ($array as $slideshow) {
    $file = File::getByID($slideshow['fID']);
}
```